# Logstash throttle filter key => multiple fields?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, throttling

I'm struggling with applying multiple fields to the key => in the throttle filter.

According to the Docs the value is a string but it doesn't say how that string should look if you use multiple keys.

I want to use %{field}, field2 works but for something like %{field}, field2, field3 the field2 value always gets skipped.

How can I make a proper string? I can't use %{field} for every field I have because some fields I want to log only once every 1 hour regardless of the value (done with "field") while for other fields I need to log every unique value only once per hour (can be done with %{field}).

> key edit
>
> ```
> This is a required setting.
> Value type is string
> There is no default value for this setting.
> ```
>
> The key used to identify events. Events with the same key are grouped
>   together. Field substitutions are allowed, so you can combine multiple
>   fields.

Only example given

> key => "%{host}%{message}"

Comment: can you show an example and your config content?

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

I can but the problem isn't with the config but the actual string.

throttle {
before_count => -1
after_count => 1
period => 120
max_age => 7200
key => "%{temp}%{error}%EbNo%state"
add_tag => "throttled"
}

temp and error are fine, each unique value gets logged but no unique value gets logged more than once. 

The problem is with %ebno%state. In this case I want each field to be logged only once. However the throttle is applied to both fields so if ebno appears state won't log until the reset. It should be logged once.

Comment: Apologies for the poor example, I'll post just the key again because that is where the issue is. Slackoverflow comment formatting really is horrible.

key => "%{temp}%{error}%EbNo%state"

Long story short; I need to know the correct way of writing a string for the ebno and state fields that I want to log only ONE value PER field. The current code logs only ONE value per the throttle time. 

%{field} works as intended.

Comment: if you only need string fromating rules, thats simple. every variable should be in %{<variablename>} format. with throttle behaviour i cant help, sry

Comment: The problem is that %{field} doesn't give the required results for all my fields.

Anyway I ended up working around the problem by using a dozen or so "if" statements to apply a separate throttle to each of the fields. Not pretty but it works.